# ActionMessages not getting displayed - Struts 1

Tags: jsp, struts

I am trying to display some warning messages on a form submission in Struts1.
But the messages are not getting displayed.

**Observation:** I have another collection called 'errors' for saving error messages. When there is some error message, the warning message also shows up.

Action:

```
messages.add(BizValidator.validatePostalZipCode(form));
saveMessages(request, messages);
```

JSP:

```
<html:errors bundle="ERRORS"/>

<logic:messagesPresent message="true">
  <html:messages id="actionMessage" bundle="ERRORS" message="true">
    <logic:present name="actionMessage">
      <ul id="messages">
        <li class="warnMsg"><bean:write name="actionMessage"/></li>
      </ul>
    </logic:present>
  </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

Is something missing over here?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javaScript function on `onclick` event on the button.

Comment: Are you sure you're answering the same question?